# Substituting variable inside a string stored in array - bash

Tags: bash, unix

My strings are stored inside array, a sample string contains a 'variable'.
While iterating over this array, I want to substitute the 'variable' with a 'value'.

This fails for me. I have tried my lot in various ways & googled but could not figure it out

```
# Array of strings (each string is a command)
clean_aa_commands=(
    "sourceanalyzer -b ${FortifyBuildId} -clean"    
    "cd ${unifiedbuilddir}/AA/AAUI"
    "mvn clean"
)  

# Functions  
function check {
    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Operation [$1] Unsuccessful!"
    else
        echo "Operation [$1] Success!"  
    fi
    }

function runcmds {
        echo "using $FortifyBuildId *************************"
        cmdArr=("${!1}")
        for cmd in "${cmdArr[@]}"
        do
            echo "-->Running [$cmd]"
            eval "$cmd"
            check "$cmd"
            echo ""
            echo ""
        done
    }

   # main
   FortifyBuildId="$1"
   echo "FortifyBuildId is $FortifyBuildId"
   unifiedbuilddir=`pwd`
   runcmds clean_aa_commands["@"]
```

Comment: Runas: bash script.sh foo

Comment: [Use More Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Comment: `runcmds "clean_aa_commands[@]"`

Comment: i see that the variable in the arrays gets substituted at the time of script launch. So if I change this variable during scipt execution, it does not get substituted. Thinking of avoiding substitution & going for 'mark with a placeholder' replace this 'placeholder' using regex

Comment: i want that the array gets the new value of variable (as & when I change the variable) & call 'runcmds'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
cmds='cmds=( /test/$mydir  /test/$test )'

mydir=$(pwd)
test="me"

eval ${cmds}
echo ${cmds[@]}
```